# CS50 Introduction to Programming with Python: Problem with Check50 in PSet4

Tags: python, cs50

I'm taking CS50 Introduction to Programming with Python. I have problem with PSet4 (Little Professor). I don't have any problem while running, but when check50 running it keeps giving this error: "Little Professor accepts valid level timed out while waiting for program to exit." While I’m manually running the program, it accepts any level value lower than 4. But the check50 says otherwise.  Here is my code:

```
import random

def main():
    try:
        level = input("Level: ")
        first, second = get_level(level)
        game_on(first, second, 0, 2, 0, level)
    except WrongInputError:
        main()

def get_level(x):
    try:
        x = int(x)
        if 0 < x < 4:
            first = generate_integer(x)
            second = generate_integer(x)
            return first, second
        else:
            raise WrongInputError
    except ValueError:
        raise WrongInputError


class WrongInputError(Exception):
    """You entered something wrong, try again """

def generate_integer(level):
    if level == 1:
        integer = random.randrange(10)
        return integer
    elif level == 2:
        x = str(random.randrange(1, 10))
        y = str(random.randrange(10))
        integer = int(x + y)
        return integer
    elif level == 3:
        x = str(random.randrange(1, 10))
        y = str(random.randrange(10))
        z = str(random.randrange(10))
        integer = int(x + y + z)
        return integer

def game_on(x , y, count, lives, score, level):
    game_set = [x, y]
    try:
        if count < 10:
            calculation = int(input(f"{x} + {y} = "))
            count += 1
            if calculation == sum(game_set):
                score +=1
                first, second = get_level(level)
                game_on(first, second, count, 3, score, level)
            elif calculation == sum(game_set):
                print("EEE")
                if lives > 0:
                    lives -= 1
                    count -= 1
                    game_on(x, y, count, lives, score, level)
                elif lives == 0:
                    print(f"{x} + {y} = {sum(game_set)}")
                    first, second = get_level(level)
                    game_on(first, second, count, 2, score, level)
        else:
            print(f"Score: {score}")
    except ValueError:
        print("EEE")
        if lives > 0:
            lives -= 1
            game_on(x, y, count, lives, score, level)
        elif lives == 0:
            print(f"{x} + {y} = {sum(game_set)}")
            first, second = get_level(level)
            game_on(first, second, count, 2, score, level)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

main()
```

Comment: Just curious, aren't you running the code twice based on the last 3 lines?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import random

def main():
    num = get_level()

    errors = 1
    score = 0

    for i in range(10):
        x = generate_integer(num)
        for j in range(1):
            y = generate_integer(num)

            answer = x + y
            equation = input(f"{x} + {y} = ")

            if int(equation) == answer:
                score += 1

            while int(equation) != answer:
                errors += 1
                print("EEE")
                equation = input(f"{x} + {y} = ")
                if errors >= 3:
                    print(answer)
                    sys.exit("Score: " + str(score))

    print("Score: " + str(score))

# prompt for level and reprompt if needed
def get_level():
    levelChoice = input("Level: ")

    if levelChoice.isalpha() or int(levelChoice) <= 0 or int(levelChoice) > 3:
        input("Level: ")
    else:
        levelChoice = int(levelChoice)
        for i in [1,2,3]:
            if levelChoice == i:
                return levelChoice

# generate int from level choice
def generate_integer(level):
    try:
        if level == 1:
            return random.randint(0, 9)
        elif level == 2:
            return random.randint(10, 99)
        elif level == 3:
            return random.randint(100, 999)
    except:
        raise ValueError

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This answer, while the code may be correct, could use some text explaining what you did differently to solve the question.